# Backup during installation of ubuntu alongside windows

Tags: system-installation, backup

Is it necessary to create a backup before installing Ubuntu on Windows 7? If so, how do I do that in as little time as possible??

Comment: Are you installing Ubuntu through Wubi or on a separate partition?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a requirement that you make a backup of your windows system, and a recovery disk, and make sure that you have installation media on hand, **but** it is a very, very good idea.

There are often questions on this site from people who have installed Ubuntu, only to discover that something has happened to their windows partitions.  The ability to recover from this depends upon having a recent backup.

As to the speed of the backup process, this will depend upon the media, the computer and of course windows itself.  It's never fast but I believe that I can assure you that it will be much faster than recreating important data by hand.